# mysql Correctly pull data from multiple tables without duplicates and incorrect data

Tags: mysql

## The Scenario/Use Case

Teachers allow their students to play games with kids from other teachers and grades and earn points for playing.  Groups are formed by teachers and kids are placed into the groups.

So, A teacher has an account and therefore is a **User**.  A **User** has **UserInfo** and has **Kid**'s associated with them.  A teacher(e.g. **User**) then selects a **Kid** to be put into a **PlayerGroup**.

## The Issue

I've got the db-fiddle that contains the database built out and my stab at the query (I realize the query isn't very good, sorry!).  I'm sort-of able to pull the data I want but each kid shows under each teacher so each kid is duplicated 3 times.  The query I made is pulling for only 3 kids, groups can have up to 5 so I'll need up date it later.

I have tried using JOIN's, GROUP BY's, using IN instead of "=" but I'm unable to get the desired output, even with searching Google and StackOverflow.

## The Desired Output

I just want to pull kids info and their teacher information for specific groups (e.g. playergroupid = 200) without it showing duplicates and being incorrect.

## Before you comment on database structure...

This code was set up quickly as an example of the to-be database.  Please no comments on case sensitivity, type chosen, etc as those will be updated before the actual build.  I'm just looking for help with the query. Thank you for understanding.

## OK, Here We Go!

DB-Fiddle with everything built out and ready to go!

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3ZEncyTteSoTVeybSaRbq/0

```
CREATE TABLE User(
userid int,
username varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE UserInfo(
userid int,
name varchar(255),
bio varchar(255),
kid1 int,
kid2 int,
kid3 int,
kid4 int,
kid5 int,
PRIMARY KEY (userid),
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES User(userid)
);

CREATE TABLE PlayerGroup(
playergroupid int,
createdby int,
teacher1id int,
kid1id int,
teacher2id int,
kid2id int,
teacher3id int,
kid3id int,
PRIMARY KEY (playergroupid),
FOREIGN KEY (createdby) REFERENCES User(userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Kid(
kidid int,
points int,
kidname varchar(255),
kidgrade varchar(255),
teacherid int,
PRIMARY KEY (kidid),
FOREIGN KEY (teacherid) REFERENCES User(userid)
);
```

Now the SQL Query

```
SET @v_groupid = 200;

Select  ui.name as "Teacher Name", kid.kidname as "Kid Name", kid.points, kid.kidgrade
FROM (
  Select kidname, points, kidgrade
  FROM Kid
  WHERE kidid=
    (
    Select kid1id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
    OR kidid = 
    (
    Select kid2id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
    OR kidid = 
    (
    Select kid3id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
)
as kid,
(
  SELECT name
  FROM UserInfo
  WHERE userid = 
    (
    Select teacher1id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
    OR userid = 
    (
    Select teacher2id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
    OR userid = 
    (
    Select teacher3id
    FROM PlayerGroup
    WHERE playergroupid = @v_groupid
    )
)as ui
```

**UPDATE**

Adding table structure that I envisioned
[image]

Comment: It's bad practice to have columns like `kid1`, `kid2`, `kid3`, or `teacher1`, etc.  Instead, have a table that lists eg `playergroupid` and  `kidid` to support this one-to-many relationship (one playergroup, many kids).  I'll do a fiddle.  Excellent prep for this question, by the way.

Comment: What's the meaning of `kid.teacherid` if `UserInfo` also holds `kididX`?

Comment: @DanFarrell I updated the question with a very basic diagram of how I imagined the table structure.  The meaning of kid.teacherid was to associated the kid to a teacher.  You're correct though that because UserInfo also holds kidix then it's repetitive.  One or the other could be removed.  Poor design on my part, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is making the queries hard. Rather than `UserInfo` having 5 columns, create

```
CREATE TABLE Class (
userid int,
kidid int,
PRIMARY KEY (userid, kidid)
);
```

Maybe is class has a name it could be a different table however the kidid->userid relationship seems to be duplicated in various places.

Same with `PlayerGroup` taking away the list of names and a separate table of called PlayGroupMembers to define members:

```
CREATE PlayGroupMembers (
playergroupid int,
userid int,
kidid int,
PRIMARY KEY (playergroupid, userid, kidid)
```

(is the userid for the kidid here really just the Class mapping? or the kid.teacherid?)

Then results come easier like:

```
SELECT pg.*, ui.*, k.*
FROM PlayGroupMembers pgm
JOIN PlayerGroup pg
  ON pgm.playergroupid = pg.playergroupid
JOIN UserInfo ui
  ON pgm.userid = ui.userid
JOIN kid k
  ON pgm.kidid = k.kidid
WHERE pgm.playergroupid = @v_groupid
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll spend some time on this today looking to make the changes you've outlined here.  Once I've got it all working I can mark this as correct.